# Getting Scanner Errors On Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, java.util.scanner

I recently purchased Scite for Mac but am having issues using the Scanner class. Compiles fine, but when I run it I get errors.

This is the code. Works fine on Windows but cannot get to work on Mac OSx.

```
   `import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Power2Input{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter TWO integer numbers!");
    int a=0;
    System.out.println("First number: ");
    a=input.nextInt();
    int b=0;
    System.out.println("Second number: ");
    b=input.nextInt();
    double c=Math.pow(a, b);
    System.out.println((int)c);
}
```

}`

This is the error message.

```
    `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Power2Input.main(Power2Input.java:10)`
```

Comment: Working fine on my mac, what numbers are you entering in the console?

Comment: Hi Matthew. I dont get to add any numbers. It compiles but when I run it I get that error. It seems that maybe i need to configure something so it can run on Mac. Did you need to configure Scite on your Mac? As an example I know that I need to 'Allow Access to Path...' in order to save the work before I can run it. Maybe I am missing something else in order for Scanner class to run?

Comment: Sorry I'm running from intellij. Your code is ok, so it's something with your setup.

Comment: I know its got something to do with the setup, thats why Im asking if anyone has come across this issue, then how did they correct it?